# AppCombatImageView could not be substantiated when I drop and drag an 'ImageView'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm very new to Android studio, but when I drag an `ImageView` to my screen, I choose my picture from drawable, but then I get a Render error saying this:

```
The following classes could not be substantiated:
    - android.support.v7.widget.AppCombatImageView
```

Any idea what the problem is? The `ImageView` looks fine in the XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shopCentre"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/shopping-centre"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" />
```

**build.gradle (Project: App)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Show me your build.gradle file

Comment: use android:src="@drawable/shopping_centre" instead of app:srcCompat

Comment: That worked, thanks @JaydeepPatel